# STL list Code that compiles in Visual Studio 2013 gives error in Visual Studio 2019. Wanted to know the reason

Tags: c++

While compiling the following C++ / STL code on Visual Studio 2019 it gives following compilation error:

`no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list argument types are: (Client::SetInstObj (std::string (*)(_bstr_t bsName), std::string (*)(_bstr_t bsInstance))) object type is: std::list<Client::SetInstObj, std::allocator<Client::SetInstObj>>`

**Code that reproduces the error in Visual Studio 2019:**

```
`class Client 
 {      
    public:
            Client();
            Client(string szURL);
            ~Client();

            static string s_szUserName;
            static string s_szVersion;

            class SetInstObj
            {
                public:
                SetInstObj(string szModelName, string szInstance)
                {
                    ModelName = szModelName;
                    Instance = szInstance;
                }
                string ModelName;
                string Instance;
             };
          };

        bool GetModelInst(list<Client::SetInstObj> &modelInstance)
        {
            bool bRetVal = true;

            CComBSTR bsName;
            CComBSTR bsInstance;

            Client::SetInstObj instanceObject(string(_bstr_t(bsName)), 
            string(_bstr_t(bsInstance)));
            modelInstance.push_back(instanceObject);

           return bRetVal;
        }
```

`

The code compiles properly in Visual Studio 2013.

**The following Code fixes the compilation issue in Visual Studio 2019:**

```
`   
CComBSTR bsName;
CComBSTR bsInstance;
Client::SetInstObj instanceObject(string(_bstr_t(bsName.m_str)), 
string(_bstr_t(bsInstance)));
modelInstance.push_back(instanceObject);
`
```

Wanted to know what is the reason for the error seen in Visual Studio 2019?

Answer (score 2):

While this is a breaking change, it's a good thing.  It means MSVS is more standard compliant now. This is a [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) issue that MSVS 2013 was not handling correctly. When you have

```
Client::SetInstObj instanceObject(string(_bstr_t(bsName)), string(_bstr_t(bsInstance)));
```

You aren't actually creating a `Client::SetInstObj` named `instanceObject`.  Instead, `string(_bstr_t(bsName))` is interpreted as as a unnamed function pointer that returns a `string` and takes a `_bstr_t` named `bsName`.  The same thing happens to `string(_bstr_t(bsInstance))` which means you actually have

```
Client::SetInstObj instanceObject(string(*)(_bstr_t), string(*)(_bstr_t));
```

which in turn means `instanceObject` is not an object, but instead is a function declaration that declares a function that returns a `Client::SetInstObj` and takes two `string(*)(_bstr_t)`.

To fix this you can use [uniform initialization](https://mbevin.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/uniform-initialization/) by replacing the `()` with `{}` to denote you want to create an object instead of a function.  That would change the code to

```
Client::SetInstObj instanceObject{string{_bstr_t{bsName}}, string{_bstr_t{bsInstance}}};
```

---

The reason

```
Client::SetInstObj instanceObject(string(_bstr_t(bsName.m_str)), string(_bstr_t(bsInstance)));
```

works is because `string(_bstr_t(bsName.m_str))` cannot be interprited as a function pointer since `bsName.m_str` is not a valid parameter name.  This then tells the compiler you are not creating a function but instead creating an object.